# Oracle SQL Regexp capture only the number from the string

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr, regexp-like

I am trying to extract the number from the row.

i am trying this in Oracle 11G

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
COL_NAME VARCHAR2(100)
);


insert into test1 values ('DWH_SCHEMA_BI.AB_25_BC_ORDER_STATUS');


select COL_NAME, REGEXP_REPLACE(COL_NAME, '^([A-Z0-9$]{17,})_.*', '\17') as BEGINNING from TEST1
and COL_NAME='DWH_SCHEMA_BI.AB_25_BC_ORDER_STATUS'
```

**EXISTING RESULT**

```
COL_NAME                             BEGINNING
DWH_SCHEMA_BI.AB_25_BC_ORDER_STATUS  DWH_SCHEMA_BI.AB_25_BC_ORDER_STATUS
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
COL_NAME                             BEGINNING
DWH_SCHEMA_BI.AB_25_BC_ORDER_STATUS  25
```

Total Patterns

```
DWH_SCHEMA_BI.AB_25_BC_ORDER_STATUS
DWH_SCHEMA.ABC_02_BC_ORDER_STATUS
DWH_BID.ABC_11_BC_ORDER_STATUS
```

Please note i have total 3 patterns, how to achieve the desired result , seems my REGEXP logic is not working as per the EXPECTED RESULTS

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8aafffde010ae586f8a79974ee1ff140

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select t1.*,
       regexp_substr(col_name, '[0-9]+')
from test1 t1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5f92a67525b70566fb37c34be5eff60) is a db<>fiddle.